# How to show Dynamic Json data in Dynamic generated input-angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I try to show dynamic JSON data in dynamic generated input angularJS.

```
{
"social": [
    {
        "id": "5694",
        "types": "4",
        "type": 4,
        "web": "https://www.xing.com",
        "title": "Xing"
    },
    {
        "id": "5695",
        "types": "7",
        "type": 7,
        "web": "https://www.blog.com",
        "title": "Blog"
    }
],
"webtypes": {
    "1": "LinkedIn",
    "2": "Website",
    "3": "Facebook",
    "4": "Xing",
    "5": "Twitter",
    "6": "Experteer",
    "7": "Blog",
    "8": "Skype",
    "9": "Windows",
    "10": "Google",
    "11": "Viadeo",
    "12": "Github",
    "13": "Youtube",
    "14": "CrunchBase",
    "15": "AngelList",
    "16": "Glassdoor"
},
"success": 1
```

}

Try to generate input field based on JSON data

```
<fieldset class="noborders" data-ng-repeat="social in socials">
      <select ng-model="socialselect[social.title]" ng-options="key as value for  (key , value) in webtypes">
      </select>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="socialinput[social.id]" ng-value="{{social.web}}" >
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

I am not able to get data by using "`ng-model`". Please help me.

Comment: it should be `ng-model="social.title"` and not `socialselect[social.title]`

Comment: Show your complete JSON. Don't understand how you wrote expression to `ng-model`

Comment: Chanve `ng-value="{{social.web}}"` to `ng-value="social.web"`

Comment: @Korte Thanks for your reply, but when I try to get data from input data show blank- $scope.socialinput: Object {}, If I simply edit or update single character in input then I get data - $scope.socialinput: Object {5694: "https://www.xing.com"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3z24LLf/4/) and change `ng-value="{{ social.web }} "` to `ng-value="social.web"` - [AngularJS ng-value documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <fieldset class="noborders" data-ng-repeat="social in socials">
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" ng-model="social.web">
      </label>
  </fieldset>
  <button ng-click="submit()">
   Send form
  </button>
</div>
```

AngularJS Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.socials = [
      {
          "id": "5694",
          "types": "4",
          "web": "https://www.xing.com",
          "title": "Xing"
      },
      {
          "id": "5695",
          "types": "7",
          "web": "https://www.blog.com",
          "title": "Blog"
      }
  ];

  $scope.submit = function () {
      console.log($scope.socials);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I try to get data from input data show blank- `$scope.socialinput:  Object {}`, If I simply edit or update single character in input then I get data - `$scope.socialinput:  Object {5694: "https://www.xing.com"}`

Comment: @Neotrixs nice, thats how it works. Whats the problem with it? Do you need it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r3z24LLf/2/ ?

Comment: There is two JSON data If I update or edit only one input field then I get only one input field data I am not get another input field data

Comment: yes almost, but how can I get back data from input field.

Comment: @Neotrixs I added a success button to show you how you can access the input data. The input data is stored in attribute `web`. For example `$scope.socials[0].web` for the first field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136249/discussion-between-neotrixs-and-lin).